# How to build a livecd without dev entry points for local hard drives

Tags: boot, live-usb, customization, devices

I'm trying to create a bootable USB key with "livecd" lubuntu distribution (lubuntu-22.04.1-desktop-amd64) for a specific purpose: a restricted OS for students examinations. I'm almost done with it (networking automatic configuration and restriction, script to mount specific accounts of exam server on LAN, etc.) but I'm still facing a complex issue: how to tell lubuntu to NOT create the /dev/ entry points of local hard disks...

I'm able to rm /dev/nvXXX on my test PC after boot but I'm not sure it will be the same dev entry points for every student's PC (or perhaps get from /etc/mtab the dev entry points that are not those of USB-livecd and delete them). It would by easier if lubuntu could be skip these entry points creation at boot time.

Any idea ? Or another way to achieve my goal ?

Thanks a lot !

EP

Comment: What version of the OS are you using?

Comment: I'm using lubuntu-22.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso

Comment: Maybe explain why you need this? Coukd be you are focusing on getting something done that is avoidable. Mind though that `rm /etc/nv*`  will remove all of `nv`. Usb will be `/dev/sd*`

Comment: The Lubuntu ISO (like all Ubuntu ISOs) installs the fastest way possible, ie. expanding a *squashfs* included on the installation media to the drive/device you're installing to. Any changes/cleanup (inc.. minimal install or removal of packages) is done after that (*you want a variation of minimal as I see it*)  The *minimal* install option isn't available with `calamares` Lubuntu uses; but it's a post-expansion removal of packages (*alas you want files; but similar*) but Lubuntu has no such option - https://phab.lubuntu.me/T58 maybe helpful